# base64 encode image blob not showing in IE

Tags: php, image, internet-explorer, base64, encode

```
  echo '<img src="data:image/jpg/png/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['image'] ) . '" height="150" />';
```

This is showing up images great in firefox, safari and chrome, but in internet explorer it shows a nice red cross, and I assume it is because of the encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `data:image/jpg/png/jpeg;` with either `data:image/jpeg;` or `data:image/png;` depending on the format of the image.  You can't expect it to be both a PNG *and* a JPEG.

Comment: I tried, thanks for the suggestion, but I am including different extensions and we are not sure what image gets uploaded.

Comment: You need to detect this in your php code (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php).  "image/jpg/png/jpeg" is not a valid mime type.

Comment: I see but doesnt that mean it shouldnt be able to work in firefox & chrome

Comment: FF & Chrome may be generous with errors like that, as they are with many malformed HTML documents.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely old IE or too big image for IE8.

IE7 and below definitely don't support it. IE9 support inline images just fine. I IE8 have limited support. - Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme for list.

Comment: Tried updating my IE to 9 and still don't work, any other ideas? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm not totally sure how resulting HTML looks like, so no particular ideas. Followong page works fine for me in IE9- http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/folder-test.html (from http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/ article) - see if it helps.