# alternative for base64 java

Tags: java, image, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, awt

Is there an alternative way to convert `BLOB` type to an image other than `Base64 encoding` or giving the `servlet` path inside image src attribute?
The images are dynamic (so am not sure that weather 
[Dean's](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-sexy/)  technique would work or not).
The data uri am using is `src="data:image/png;base64,[base64 String]`

The technologies, that I am using are `java` , `jsp`, `js`, `Twitter Bootstrap`(for carousel display).
So is there any alternatives technique to get the blob type and convert it to image other than `Base64` encoding/decoding

Comment: How do you figure this has ***anything*** to do with Swing?

Comment: I have used the tag `swing` because am using `Ghraphics2D` class to resize the image ... But it doesn't work for **IE** so googled for alternatives but couldn't find any

Comment: Your question is completely incoherent. Tell us *exactly* and *precisely* what you are trying to do, what you have tried to do, and what is not working.

Comment: Well, JavaScript uses base64 encoding for canvas images, so I would stick with it. If you want to recall image data from a database using Java and push said data to JavaScript, why do extra work converting that data?

Comment: Through `jQuery ajax` call am calling a function inside a class which hits the `DB` and gets the `Blob` type,  then converting it to `Base64 encoded` string and passing it back as value for `image tag src` attribute with `data uri prefix data:image/png;base64,[Base64 String]` . But this doesn't work in **IE** ...so looking for alternatives for `Base64`

Comment: You need to decide if the image is a JPEG or a PNG. You cannot expect IE to figure it out. Here is the accepted answer from a similar question: *"Try replacing `data:image/jpg/png/jpeg;` with either `data:image/jpeg;` or `data:image/png;` depending on the format of the image. You can't expect it to be both a PNG and a JPEG."* [[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9963144/1762224)]

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl `Base64 encoded` String having size greater than 32kb wont be displayed completely on **IE** .. So thats why am doing all this convertion work...

Comment: If you think about it, base64 is very compact compared to raw or binary data...

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl i searched through all the questions related to `Base64 encoding` but none of the solutions worked for me. Thats why i created a new thread...

Comment: *"I have used the tag swing because am using `Ghraphics2D` class"*  That is in the **AWT package,** not Swing!